# How should I use the fact that F(x) can be bounded on part b) of this question?

Tags: integration

[image]

I understood part A) and about defining ø(0) and ø(1) so that the function to integrate is uniformly continuous on [0,1], but I cannot comprehend how to compute $\lim_{x->0^+} F(x)$ for part B). A hint my professor gave is to bound F(x), but how does that help when I don't even understand how that will allow me to compute the exact value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x >0$ we have $|\frac {y^{x}-1} {\log y}|=\frac {1-e^{-x|\log y|}} {|\log y|}\leq \frac {x|\log y|} {|\log y|} =x$ so $F(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0+$.

Comment: How did you think of the property 1-e^-x <= x for all real number x? Is it from past experience? Thank you though!

Comment: Yes, when you are trying to find  a bound for $|y^{x}-1|$ you think of the well known inequality $1-e^{-t}\leq t$ for $t \geq 0$. I could think of it  immediately because I have already used  it hundreds of times! @LHC2012